# React router, link to component and show in url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jtcfzn?file=Main.tsx)

Its a simple react app using react-router-dom to link to two pages, Home and Info

On the Info page I have two further links.

I would like these links to load components below the links on this page, is this possible with react-router.

Also is it possible to add this link to the url so it would be something like `/info/infolinkone`

Is this the best way to do this ore does react do it another way.

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Info:React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Info</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><Link>Info Link One</Link></li>
        <li><Link>Info Link Two</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        //Load components here
      </div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know if this can help you

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Route, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";

const Info: React.FC = () => {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Info</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${path}/linkone`}>Info Link One</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link>Info Link Two</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        <Route exact path={`${path}/linkone`}>
          //here you load your component
        </Route>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

Comment: I get this error if I use this code `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-p5vdeq?file=Info.tsx

Comment: I've fixed it installing also react-router dependencie https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-567mno?file=Info.tsx . Its not necessary to write React.FC for every component. You can write directly with an arrow function